# How to return the value properly in recursion with python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I wish to implement a function which can recurs the input array `a` and calculate the value of `a_i - a_j` where `i` is in `(len(a))`, `j = i -1` and return a list as output finally. So given an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, the result would be `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

My code is as follow:

```
import numpy as np
def recur_diff(array, result_array=None):
    l = len(array)
    if l > 1:
        diff = array[-1] - array[-2]
        if result_array is None:
            result_array = np.array([diff])

        else:
            result_array = np.append(result_array, diff)
        recur_diff(array[:-1], result_array)
    else:
        return result_array
```

However the result returned is `None`. And if I `print result_array`, the output is what I expect. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `return` to the recursive call to `recur_diff` in `recur_diff(array[:-1], result_array)`. Otherwise the results will never be returned back to upper levels

```
if l > 1:
    # ...
    return recur_diff(array[:-1], result_array)
else:
    return result_array
```

Just as a hint: instead of manipulating the result_array and pass it to the next level you could compute the next level and merge/work with the result on the current level. In many cases this is cleaner code. (In your example you'd know for sure the returned value is an array, instead of testing for `None`)